# Site URL changed by mistake of my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

Few days ago by mistake i changed my website's siteurl in word press admin pannel before it was `http://www.kathiyawadikhamir.com`, I changed it to `localhost/wordpress-3.8.1/wordpress/`
so as a reflection my website's `wp-admin` area was inaccessible, so I re enter original site address through database in `phpmyadmin` and now my `wp-admin` area is working but when I go to `Sharing Settings (Publicize)` and try to connect Facebook or Google+ it reflect that `localhost` address and not working can any one help me on this?
It's showing path like below:

`(http://localhost/wordpress-3.8.1/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sharing&action=completed&service=facebook&id=6722195#_=_)`

How to change above path to my original website??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to change the site URL in your case is directly editing the values inside the `MySQL` database.

The table, where this information is stored is called `wp_options` (this table *may* have prefix, it depends on how exactly you have installed the WordPress, but anyway it ends with `wp_options`).

So login inside the `phpmyadmin` area, find this table and edit the value of `option_name` called `siteurl`, then find one more `option_name` value, called `home`.
These two values are important ones.

Comment: yes thanks, i do that earlier, and now my wp-admin area is accessible, but when i try to connect facebook or google+ Publicize, it returns this url

http://localhost/wordpress-3.8.1/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sharing&action=completed&service=facebook&id=6722195#_=_

so i think i still need to change url somewhere